# SUMIFS e COUNTIFS with only filtered rows of my table

Tags: excel

I've a table with some **filters** on it, and I have a vba module that should use the **sumifs** and **countifs** function (*Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs, Application.WorksheetFunction.Sumifs*), but they actually work on the complete table. Can someone provide me an easy solution? Can't I isolate my range with `tabella.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and use it for the parameter of the sumifs?

I saw some similar questions, but the solutions given are not understandable by me...

Comment: No, `tabella.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a disjointed range and both formula do not accept disjointed ranges. You will need to loop the areas and cells in the visible cells and do the math and count.

Comment: There is someone who already have done this? Some replica of countifs and sumifs? I m not great at VBA:(

Comment: What about using `SUBTOTAL`?

Comment: How can it helps me?

Comment: Using it, you can exclude hidden cells from calculation.

Comment: I think what you are asking for has [been done at MrExcel - Countif- Visible Cells in Filter mode](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/countif-visible-cells-in-filter-mode.56984/)

Comment: I guess your table is filtered based on some conditions. Use those conditions too in SUMIF and COUNTIF. Or even use different Pivot Tables to get desired output

Answer (score 0):

SUBTOTAL function

This article describes the formula syntax and usage of the SUBTOTAL function in Microsoft Excel.

Description

Returns a subtotal in a list or database. It is generally easier to create a list with subtotals by using the Subtotal command in the Outline group on the Data tab in the Excel desktop application. Once the subtotal list is created, you can modify it by editing the SUBTOTAL function.

Syntax

SUBTOTAL(function_num,ref1,[ref2],...)

The SUBTOTAL function syntax has the following arguments:

◾ Function_num     Required. The number 1-11 or 101-111 that specifies the function to use for the subtotal. 1-11 includes manually-hidden rows, while 101-111 excludes them; filtered-out cells are always excluded.